Задержка обновления информации о доступности агента zabbix
При включении/отключении агента информация о его доступности обновляется спустя 30-40 секунд.
Возможно ли убрать эту задержку, в моем  приложении критически важно, чтобы информация поступала без задержек, максимум 3-5 сек.
Шаблонные триггеры в узле пытался перенастроить, выставил везде интервал обновления в 1 секунду, не помогло.

@aleksandr-barakin, как в таком случае тестировать работоспособность приложения?
при включении/выключении агента информация о том агент какого устройства был выключен/включен и время этого включения/отключения должна сразу же отображаться

прошу прощения, если своим ответом сбил с толку.
не понимаю, что значит "пробовали не отключать агента?". Как еще вы предлагаете проверить задержку при обновлении информации о доступности узла?

да, думаю, что ваш вопрос очень похож на проблему xy

У меня сильные подозрения, что Zabbix (и его аналоги вроде Prometheus) принципиально не предназначен для такого
